# sqlite3 default on update conditionally

Tags: sqlite, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    val INTEGER,
    dt INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now'))
)

CREATE TRIGGER tr AFTER UPDATE OF val
ON t
BEGIN
  UPDATE t SET dt=strftime('%s','now') WHERE id=NEW.id;
END;

INSERT INTO t (1, 11)
```

Now when I do

```
UPDATE t SET val=2 WHERE id=1
```

It is working ok, but when I want to specify dt:

```
UPDATE t SET val=2, dt=140000 WHERE id=1
```

Trigger overwrite my new dt. How to get both of that two examples working ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not `BEFORE UPDATE OF val`? The trigger will update dt to current (takes care of case 1), then the `UPDATE` will update dt to the desired (takes care of case 2).